# Need help fixing a vba Error '1004' after editing a section of code

Tags: excel, vba

Some background, I've written a piece of code that cycles through all workbooks in a directory and executes a function, and that function also executes another function. Both functions tested fine and worked without an issue until I put them into the code that goes through all workbooks.
I had this code originally and had no problems with it:

```
Set tbl = shtOfErrors.UsedRange
tbl.Offset(2, 0).SpecialCells(2, 23).Select
Selection.Resize(, 3).Select
```

I was trying to get rid of all .select I had in the original functions, because it kept erroring when it was called as part of the workbook loop. But now I get an error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error here on line 3 :

```
Set tbl = shtOfErrors.UsedRange
Set selrng = tbl.Offset(2, 0).SpecialCells(2, 23)
Set seltbl = selrng.Resize(, 3)
```

Comment: Seems you qualified sheet for `tbl` but you want to do that for workbook as well. (+1 for ridding of `select`).

Comment: `Resize` is an action done on a range.  An action cannot be assigned to a variable.  Just replace `Set seltbl = selrng.Resize(, 3)` with `selrng.Resize(, 3)` and it should work correctly.  (If we assume the rest of the code that has not been presented is also correct)

Comment: @Demetri to make it simple: `Resize` just does not return an object/range like `worksheets.copy` also does not (but `worksheets.add` will do)?

Comment: @DirkReichel So if resize doesn't return an object what do I have to do to get it to?   Basically what I need is the used range of a workskeet, without the first 2 rows, and no blank spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one option would be:

```
Set tbl = shtOfErrors.UsedRange
Set tbl = Intersect(tbl, tbl.Offset(2, 0)).Resize(, 3).SpecialCells(2, 23)
```

should do everything you want... (not tested)

another option:

```
Set tbl = shtOfErrors.Range("$2:$2", Rows(Rows.Count).Address).UsedRange.Resize(, 3).SpecialCells(2, 23)
```

a third option would be:

```
Set tbl = shtOfErrors.UsedRange.Offset(2, 0).UsedRange.Resize(, 3).SpecialCells(2, 23)
```